# iOS Device bound ID's - identifying devices

Tags: ios

I have created an app with membership feature and during sign up, I am planning to give out 10 points initially for each user. But in order to detect bulk accounts, - accounts signed just for points- I need to detect each device while signing up, and if device id is used, I should disable additional points.

I guess I might as well register into keychain with such thing as;

thisUserSignedUpAlready = YES;

But I would like to detect device ID's so even if the device is restored or so, I wouldn't give this additional credit to those devices.

Comment: Just a thought---what if there is a family sharing a device who all want to use your app and have their own accounts?  Then you would be preventing anyone but the first user to make an account from getting those points.

Comment: other sign-up's only won't have the advantage of getting +10 points. I don't see an alternative to this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just wanted to point it out to you :)  I'd first wonder if there's any disadvantage to just letting them have the 10 points--is 10 points a lot?  Can you do many things with those 10 points without working to earn more?  Is it going to do you any good to 'cheat' by making multiple accounts just to get the 10 points, or do you need to earn all your points on the same account to get good things?  If yes to any of these questions, then yeah, you don't really have an alternative.  If not, then I'd suggest not bothering to protect against this kind of cheating--if the benefit is to gather points...

Comment: ...on one account, then you're more likely to encounter a family sharing the device than a person trying to cheat with multiple accounts.  But anyway, this is a design decision :) Just thought I'd point it out to you!

Comment: maybe calling it "points" was misleading. What they are really are "credits" - more like coins-, and they will also be available to in-app purchase, and people wouldn't like to buy any more credits if they could just go and open another account, will they?

Comment: Well that depends. Let's say...you're making a racing game. And it costs 50 coins to buy a really cool car I want.  I get 10 free coins for signing up. Making another account to get 10 coins on it doesn't help me--I don't have 20 coins now, I have 10 coins each on 2 separate accounts. You see what I mean?  So unless coins are transferrable, making another account doesn't help me.  Now instead of being 40 coins away from the car on 1 account...I'm 40 coins away on 2 accounts.  Same difference.  Now if 10 coins can earn you real life goods, or coins are 'tradable', then that's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Mac Address, you should use the standard ways of creating a UUID. Apple does not want you tracking devices.

> To create a unique identifier specific to your app, you can call the
>   CFUUIDCreate function to create a UUID, and write it to the defaults
>   database using the NSUserDefaults class.
>   [(Source)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

If you want to use a library for this instead of rolling your own, you should use [this excellent library](https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler) instead of a MAC Address related library.

Comment: A quick question: Am I lowering my chances of my app being accepted by using either MAC Address or BPXLUUIDHandler library?

Comment: Yes on MAC address, no on BPXLUUIDHandler library.

Comment: I wish you could favorite *answers* to questions. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You should not use UDID as Apple has deprecated it. Many apps now a days are using MAC address to identify devices. You can use [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/MACAddress) category on UIDevice to find MAC address.

Comment: Most devs are not using MAC address. MAC's are a temporary workaround and are easily spoofed.

Comment: many apps that collect analytics or are based on virtual currency are using it.

Comment: Yes many, but I wouldn't say most. I would venture to say that most developers stick within Apple's recommendations.

Comment: Changed "most"->"many". My apps are also following Apple's recommendation (NSUserDefault) but I am planning to switch to MAC address soon (or may be keychain)

Comment: I wouldn't go to MAC Address if I were you. Apple is sure to deprecate access to that over time just like the UUID for the same reasons.

Comment: Is device trackable (which was Apple's main concern) using MAZ address ? If yes how ?

Comment: All networks requests send the MAC Address within the data link layer of the network packet. Thus, any software between the phone and the target server could track the device. Apple's main concerns are only speculative. They did not release any official reasons on why they did it, only that they were doing it. The safest bet for future reliability is to use their recommendation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html